# Round pie chart in rectangular canvas

Tags: chart.js, chart.js2

It it possible to get a good-looking pie chart with legend on right?

When I set a rectangular canvas bad things happen, depending on the exact combination of HTML attributes, CSS properties and Chart.js's `responsive` setting:

- Canvas becomes square and pie itself looks tiny
- Graph stretches to fit canvas and pie becomes an ellipse
- My custom size is ignored anyway and some of the two previous things happen

E.g.:

```js
new Chart("foo", {
    type: "pie",
    data: {
        labels: [
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit",
            "Morbi nec lacus",
            "Others"
        ],
        datasets: [
            {
                data: ["134", "74", "13"]
            }
        ]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        legend: {
            position: "right",
            labels: {
                usePointStyle: true
            }
        }
    }
});
```

```css
figure {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
}
canvas {
    border: 1px solid salmon;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<figure><canvas id="foo"></canvas></figure>
```

Are pie charts only designed to be square?

Comment: What do you expect it to be? Something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/an9XU.png) ?

Comment: @ℊααnd Yeah, something like that. A full height pie would be even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish so, you would need to set canvas element­*'s* width and height, using it­*'s* native attributes *(not style/css)*.

```
<canvas id="foo" width="300" height="150"></canvas>
```

***note:*** this width and height values have to be half of the values that you set for the canvas wrapper element (`<figure>`)

**ᴅᴇᴍᴏ**

```js
new Chart(foo, {
   type: "pie",
   data: {
      labels: [
         "Lorem ipsum dolor sit",
         "Morbi nec lacus",
         "Others"
      ],
      datasets: [{
         data: ["134", "74", "13"]
      }]
   },
   options: {
      responsive: true,
      legend: {
         position: "right",
         labels: {
            usePointStyle: true
         }
      }
   }
});
```

```css
figure {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
}
canvas {
   border: 1px solid salmon;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<figure>
   <canvas id="foo" width="150" height="75"></canvas>
</figure>
```

**another approach**

without canvas wrapper and setting `responsive` property to `false`

```js
new Chart(foo, {
   type: "pie",
   data: {
      labels: [
         "Lorem ipsum dolor sit",
         "Morbi nec lacus",
         "Others"
      ],
      datasets: [{
         data: ["134", "74", "13"]
      }]
   },
   options: {
      responsive: false,
      legend: {
         position: "right",
         labels: {
            usePointStyle: true
         }
      }
   }
});
```

```css
canvas {
   border: 1px solid salmon;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="foo" width="300" height="150"></canvas>
```

Comment: I have no idea why but it seems to work. So, to get a 300x150 graph I'd need `<canvas id="foo" width="150" height="75"></canvas>`?

Comment: It works nicely. Since I'm already using jQuery I've just assigned the `width` and `height` attributes dynamically after calculating them from the parent `<figure>`. Is this hack something specific to Chart.js or it's generally required when working with Canvas?

Comment: It's general. You should always set canvas's width and height using its inline attributes instead of css. Though, part of it *(first approach)* is specific to chartjs. I would suggest using the second approach.

Comment: Funny... In my real code, I've tried removing the *width divided by 2* hack and it still renders fine... :-?

Comment: Totally depends on chartjs, how it renders the chart. varies from chart to chart *(or version)*. as a result, several ways of achieving the same.